Swift with Facetec crash: libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept
I have a project in Swift for iOS that has the integration of the Facetec library.
My backend colleagues managed to create a server to use this service in production.
This is how I configured the function that helps me connect to the service:
     static func initializeFaceTecSDKFromAutogeneratedConfig(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
          guard let productionKeyJson = AppConfig.shared.productionKeyDetails?.toJsonString() else {
              print("Error: Production key is missing to initialize the SDK.")
              completion(false)
              return
          }

          let deviceKeyIdentifier = AppConfig.shared.DeviceKI
          let faceScanEncryptionKey = AppConfig.shared.publicKey
          
          if deviceKeyIdentifier.isEmpty || faceScanEncryptionKey.isEmpty {
              print("Error: Missing device configuration or encryption key to initialize the SDK.")
              completion(false)
              return
          }

          FaceTec.sdk.initializeInProductionMode(
              productionKeyText: productionKeyJson,
              deviceKeyIdentifier: deviceKeyIdentifier,
              faceScanEncryptionKey: faceScanEncryptionKey,
              completion: { success in
                  if success {
                      print("FaceTec SDK initialized in production mode")
                  } else {
                      print("FaceTec SDK initialization failed.")
                  }
                  completion(success)
              }
          )
      }

If I try to connect to this service the application crashes and in the console I get this error:
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::property_tree::ini_parser::ini_parser_error>: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F623130F-83F2-4E2C-9769-2E0AED9B94F0/tmp/D0200F0E-9A21-46A3-AB3C-91B294414CA0(1): '=' character not found in line

I don't understand what the error is due to, if perhaps it is my error in the application or the server is not responding as it should.
Could you help me? Please.
Thanks!
Connect to production services for the facetec happy path

"productionKeyJson" is that how it's really done? As JSON String? Check the different values for deviceKeyIdentifier & faceScanEncryptionKey?

According to my backend colleagues 'productionKeyText' should be in JSON which should be:
{
"prodmov": {
"expiryDate": "xxxx-xx-xx",
"appId": "*",
"key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"BaseURL": "https://xxxx.xxx-xxx.xxxx",
"DeviceKeyIdentifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"PublicFaceScanEncryptionKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
}
}
Yes deviceKeyIdentifier & faceScanEncryptionKey are different data.

So you put in the productionKeyText parameter again deviceKeyIdentifier & faceScanEncryptionKey? What does the doc of that method says about the parameters? Facetec is a private lib, they should have a support, maybe ask them?

No, in the variable
PublicFaceScanEncryptionKey I store a JSON in String which is the one I attached in the previous comment, in deviceKeyIdentifier I store the value that I get in 'DeviceKeyIdentifier' of the JSON and in the variable faceScanEncryptionKey it is the data obtained from PublicFaceScanEncryptionKey in the JSON.
Before asking support I would like to try to solve it through the experience that the developers have had.
